# Epsilon delta proof using asssumptions

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Prove the following using epsilon-delta definition:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

IF $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 647$ AND $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$, then

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \infty.$$

Not sure about this... I've set up the definitions. I believe we will have to take a minimum between the deltas for first two limits then use it in the third.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Try using triangle inequality. $\mid f(x) + g(x) \mid \le \mid f(x) \mid + \mid g(x)\mid$.

Comment: So I notice that $|f(x) - 647 + g(x)|  \leq |f(x) - 647| + |g(x)|$.

Comment: Almost $\mid f(x) - 647 + g(x) - g(a) \mid \le \mid f(x) - 647 \mid + \mid g(x) - g(a) \mid$. This way you can get the unboundedness on the higher side. Hence, all you have to prove is for no $\delta > 0$ will you find an $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $f(a + \delta) + g(a + \delta) - f(a) - g(a) $ is bounded.

Comment: Is there some way without using $a$?

Comment: If there is no $a$ how do you name the limits?

Comment: @DavidK Doesn't $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \to \infty$ imply $g(x)$ is undefined in the neighborhood of $a$? My idea was to prove the statement using the fact that $g(x) - g(a)$ is unbounded in the neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: @PythonSage I was responding to the comment about "without using $a$".

Comment: @PythonSage I don't think you'll get far with any proof that subtracts $g(a)$ from any expression, since $g(a)$ is not a number. Moreover, finding that $g(x)$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $a$ is not enough to show that $\lim_{x\to a}=\infty.$ The limit could be $-\infty$ or might not exist.

Comment: Anyway we're wasting our time here since the question was re-asked and then answered.