# Epsilon Delta Proof: How do I use the definitions to prove

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Prove the following using epsilon-delta definition:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

If 
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 647 \tag 1$$  and
$$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty \tag 2$$
then

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + g(x) = \infty.$$

$$(1) \implies\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, s.t. |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-647| < \epsilon$$

$$(2) \implies \forall M > 0, \exists \delta_2 > 0, s.t. |x-a|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)| > M$$

Not sure about this... I've set up the definitions. I believe we will have to take a minimum between the deltas for first two limits then use it in the third.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Your idea for "taking the minimum between the two deltas" is correct. You are 90% of the way there. Try setting up the definition of $\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \infty$, and perform this plan that you've outlined.

Comment: Not sure how to use triangle inequality here though

Comment: @BisonFinch Welcome to Math SE. You asked basically the same question, but without the details in your $(1)$ and $(2)$, about an hour ago in [Epsilon delta proof using asssumptions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3627620/602049). In the future, please just update the question text instead of asking a new one since, otherwise, members here may be duplicating efforts when trying to help you.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M > 0$. You want to find a $\delta'>0$ such that $|x-a| < \delta'$ implies $f(x) + g(x) \ge M$.

By $(1)$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - 647| < 1$, which implies $f(x) > 646$.

By $(2)$ there exists $\delta_2$ such that $|x-a| < \delta_2$ implies $g(x) > M$.

Then with $\delta' = \min\{\delta, \delta_2\}$, we have $|x-a| < \delta'$ implies
both $f(x) > 646$ and $g(x) > M$, so we have $f(x) + g(x) > 646 + M > M$.